# Change file in jar

Tags: java, spring, jar

so, i have a jar file and in this jar there is another config.js file, and in this file i want to write. I have a Resource class of this file (org.springframework.core.io.Resource), so i can get a full URL or getFile() from this Resource. URL look's like this:

```
jar:file:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/code/1.1-SNAPSHOT/code-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/META-INF/config.js
```

The porblem is, if i try to getFile() from Resource i get an Exception :  cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system.
So how can i write to this file in jar?:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ZipStreams](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/) on your jar, and from there you can handle your jar.
The best way to handle your jar directly is to use [`ZipFile`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) or even better [`JarFile`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html)

Comment: Hm, than i should at first create a JarFile file:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/code/1.1-SNAPSHOT/code-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar and then getEntity /META-INF/config.js from this jar file, right?

Comment: You don't have to create anything, you open the jar with `new JarFile(pathToJar)` and then you `getEntry(yourFile)`.

Comment: And than, what can i do with this entry? How can i write in it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the api in [`java.util.zip`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html) and [`java.util.jar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/package-summary.html).
If I recall correctly, you can modify the file "inline" and save, or just modify it outside, save to a temp file, and then push the temp file back into the jar.