# Apache Commons Configuration: Save properties file within a jar

Tags: java, apache-commons-config

All the apologies for disturbing you. I have an issue with the apache commons configuration. I have a properties file that is located at the src folder of an application I am building (with Eclipse). When I run the app and trying saving into the properties file  from eclipse it works. However when I export it as a jar and try saving into the file when I run it from CLI I get the following error:

Could not save to URL rsrc:smpp-config.properties and trace shows: 
ava.net.UnknowServiceException: protocol does not support output.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: where is the properties file located in your jar?

Comment: Yes the file is packaged inside the jar

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify a file inside a jar file.

The only solution is to unzip the jar file using [ZipFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) and then modify the file.

Also refer the following question dealing with the same issue 
[Modifying a file inside a jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224817/modifying-a-file-inside-a-jar)
[Change file in jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550418/change-file-in-jar)